# How to show result in reduced form?

Tags: functions, symbolic, output-formatting

Suppose that I define $$v(t)=\sqrt{v_1(t)^2+v_2(t)^2}$$ and I want to take the derivative of this with respect to time. The result that Mathematica gives me is $$v^´ = \frac{v_1{v_1}^´+v_2{v_2}^´}{\sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2}}$$
but I want in the denominator $v$ instead of $\sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2}$. How can I do it?

Comment: Once you have defined `v[t_] = Sqrt[v1[t]^2 + v2[t]^2];` `v[t]` cannot appear in an output since the definition will be used to replace it. You must `Hold` or `Inactivate` `v[t]` to have it appear. For example, `(v'[t] // Simplify) /. Power[_, -1/2] :> 1/Inactive[v][t]` However, then the resulting expression must be explicitly activated (or release the `Hold` if that was used) when you want the definition used

Comment: Very helpful, both yours and @Nasser answers. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

I often find it better to name equations, rather than define symbols.  In this case, you start with

```
eqn =
 v[t] == Sqrt[v1[t]^2 + v2[t]^2]
```

and by relatively simple manipulation obtain

```
D[eqn, t] /. Rule @@ Reverse[1/# & /@ eqn]
(* 
Derivative[1][v][t] == (
 2 v1[t] Derivative[1][v1][t] + 2 v2[t] Derivative[1][v2][t])/(2 v[t]) *)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is the following. you must use HoldForm (or `Inactive[v][t]` as mentioned by Bob)

```
ClearAll[v,v1,v2,t]
v[t_]:=Sqrt[v1[t]^2+v2[t]^2]
Simplify[D[v[t],t]]/. 1/v[t]->1/HoldForm[v[t]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You could also use a different letter close to $v$

```
ClearAll[v,v1,v2,t,ν]
v[t_]:=Sqrt[v1[t]^2+v2[t]^2]
Simplify[D[v[t],t]]/. 1/v[t]->1/ν[t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]